# How to run powershell script under specific OU?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to bulk delete AD groups with the following powershell script:

```
$OU = "OU"

$groups = get-content "path to csv" | Get-ADGroup -Properties ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion

$groups | Set-ADObject -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion $false

$groups | Remove-ADGroup –whatif
```

However, I need this script to run under a specific OU in the domain. Tried to look it up but couldn't find anything that worked for me.
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: have you looked at the `-SearchBase` parameter of many AD cmdlets yet? [*grin*]

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this parameter. How would you implement it on the script I have attached?

Comment: i would `Read The Friendly Manual` [*grin*] ... and use that parameter to limit your actions to the items in the designated OU. the most obvious place to start would be with the `Get-ADGroup` command.

Comment: `Get-ADUser -SearchBase ...`, you can discover a list of the cmdlets parameters uses running `Get-Help Get-ADUser -ShowWindow` if you're not used to a certain command.